# No data coming through when passing an array to an AngularJS controller using a function

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, angularjs-controller

I am working on an angularjs application which uses parse to create an array of names. I then pass that array to a controller, which I use in my html. My problem is that no data is coming through and I'm not sure why. I have tested my Parse connection, and it is working correctly, and I test my controller and it is passing data correctly. It is just when I combine the two that it stops working.

parse.js

```
function playerNames() {

Parse.$ = jQuery;

Parse.initialize("my key", "my key");

var names = new Array();
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.find({
    success: function (results) {
        for (var i in results){
            var name = results[i].get("playerName");
            alert(name);
            names.push(name);
        }
        return names;
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error.message);
        return names;
    }});
};  
app.controller('NameController', ['$scope', function($scope) {$scope.names = playerNames()}]);
```

index.html

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="NameController">
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="n in names">
            <td>{{ n }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `playerNames()` doesn't return anything

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I put the return statements inside query.find.  If If I put a return statement at the end, then it would return the array before the query had a chance to populate it since it runs asynchronously.

Comment: return to `success` callback does not return to outer function. Use `$q` to create and return promise

Comment: Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/ to understand your mistake and fix it

Comment: You need a good (more between basic and good) understanding of Promises to accomplish what you want to do here. I suggest reading about them online.